# Custom Object detection in tensorflow along with existing detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have setup Tensorflow Object Detection model(e.g.SSD with coco or any other model) to detect a 'car' in a picture, which works just fine. Now I want to train the same SSD model with my own dataset using pre-trained SSD model on coco, to detect a custom object, say a 'door'. 
Q: After training the model, will the trained SSD model still be able to detect a 'car' and 'door'? Or the trained model will detect only 'door' as that's what the model is trained for.
If the trained model does not detect 'car' and 'door', how do I achieve to detect a 'car'(which is a standard object) and a 'door' which I want the model to be trained to detect a custom object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When fine-tuning a pre-trained model on a different set of classes (doesn't matter if the new set includes the old one, or included in it, etc.), the weights of each of the detection heads are initialized, since it isn't the same layer anymore.
For example, if you have an SSD detector the detection head is a convolutional head with #anchors*(4+#classes) channels. If you change #classes, the number of channels is changed, and it's not longer the same layer.
Therefore, when you fine-tune a model to detect 'car' and 'door', you'll have to train the model on both 'car' and 'door' even though the pre-trained model already knew to detect 'car'.
It could be however that since all other layers are restored, that 'car' will be detected more easily and that 'door' will need more training.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes sense.